# Getting invalid double "n\a" for Latlng values while placing multiple markers on map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, amazon-dynamodb, google-maps-markers

i am developing an app where i want to show multiple markers on map.
(Markers  are coming from database (dynamodb) and values are all in "STRING" not double). After conversion of double to string of all "Lattitudes and Longitudes" I am getting an exception of java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "n/a" and app get crashed. Because in the table one lat long is showing "na". (as you can see in picture[image: X and Y are lattitudes and longitudes])

I got stuck and dont know what to do with this empty value. Should i put some check or what? Thanks in advance

```
((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        final LatLng israel = new LatLng(31.0461, 34.8516);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(israel).title("israel"));
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(31.0461, 34.8516)).zoom(8).tilt(70).build();
        CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);
        googleMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);

        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {

              DDBExecutor.getInstance().getAllSettlements(mContext, new DDBExecutor.OnResponseListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(Object result, String message) {
                      List<SettlementsTable> lstSettlements = new ArrayList<>();
                      lstSettlements.addAll((List<SettlementsTable>) result);
                      for (SettlementsTable table : lstSettlements){
                          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(table.getX()), Double.parseDouble(table.getY()))));
                      }
                     LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                      builder.include(israel);
                      LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                      CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 200);
                      mMap.moveCamera(cu);
                      mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8), 2000, null);

                      try {
                          KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.settlements, getApplicationContext());
                          kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
                          KmlLayer kmlLayer1 = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.outposts, getApplicationContext());
                          kmlLayer1.addLayerToMap();
                          KmlLayer kmlLayer2 = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.settlements_in_pal_nghbrhd, getApplicationContext());
                          kmlLayer2.addLayerToMap();

                      } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
              });

            }
        });
```

Comment: WHat to do depends on your app.  I mean you need to account for it, but do you want to ask the user to fix the data?  Not show that point?  Something else?  THat's something you need to decide.

Comment: in that case... only that particular  Latlng should not be display but rest of the value should be shown. I mean just skip the "n\a" and show rest of the result. @GabeSechan

Comment: In that case, catching NumberFormatException and moving on to the next datapoint would be sufficient.

Comment: ok thanks let me check and upvote your commnent

Comment: Check it its double then parse if not then set value to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround with try catch

```
try {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
            LatLng(Double.parseDouble(table.getX()), 
                    Double.parseDouble(table.getY()))));
} catch (NumberFormatException ex){
    //do anything when exception occurs
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. In the catch block of the answer given by @OnkarShelke, you can
       manually add the default values in the mMap instead of simply
       handling the exception. Like:

   ```
   mMap.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.5,1.2));
   // 10.5 and 1.2 could be your default values.
   ```
2. Or since you already know the wrong value(n/a) that is causing the
   exception, you could check for that value before attempting to add into the `mMap`. Like:

   ```
   for (SettlementsTable table : lstSettlements){
       if (table.getX().equalsIgnoreCase("n/a") || table.getY().equalsIgnoreCase("n/a")) {
           // do something like add default values
       } else {
           mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(table.getX()), Double.parseDouble(table.getY()))));
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

First filter list that contains SettlementsTable object such that when there are n/a string in the object fields don't add that to object to Arraylist that you are providing to Marker object for plotting.

Comment: yes Ankit sir.. I have skipped if there is "n\a" , and added next valid value in Arraylist. Its pleasure to see that we have united here to solve my problem. Thank you so much:) :) .